# Find region and redirect to that region with sub-domain?

Tags: php, yii2

I have a **Yii 2** project with dynamic sub-domains that go to `index.php`.

I want to find the region of a user and redirect him to it.

For example, if a user goes to site.com, and his region is Las Vegas, I'm redirecting him to las-vegas.site.com.

Now when I want to redirect a user in `actionIndex`, I'm getting a redirect loop error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is your problem, getting the region .. or .. avoiding the infinite redirects?

Comment: @AmrBedair Avoiding the infinite redirects.

Comment: Then you problem id to control the redirect and do it only based on a condition for example you can send a param r to the index indicating the region and if this param exists do not do more redirects .. so redirect only if r is the default null value